# How to add content to newsletter/manage/ page from XML in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, newsletter, page

I want to add the **newsletter sign up(image)** from default magento footer into newsletter/manage/ page which now it's empty.
[image]

Does anyone know how can i add this via XML? Or where i can find the XML responsabile for this page?

Answer (score 0):

After few minutes searching i found that the XML that render this page it's  `layout\newletter.xml:`

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

in my case i have this line added : `<remove name=”left.newsletter”/>`